# Sonar time is one hour behind

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

My sonar is running within the same tomcat server as Jenkins. Jenkins build would publish the analysis to sonar. I can see the same timestamp in tomcat log and sonar.log:

### catalina.out

Apr 23, 2014 1:53:16 PM hudson.model.Run execute
INFO: hcs-parent-build #217 main build action completed: SUCCESS

### Jenkins console (for Sonar plugin)

```
...
[INFO] [12:53:23.147] Load batch settings
[INFO] [12:53:23.282] User cache: /root/.sonar/cache
[INFO] [12:53:23.290] Install plugins
...
```

Somehow the timestamp is one hour behind in sonar console (Last Analysis of the main dashboard). Could someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: One is set for Daylight Savings Time, another one not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You have to set TZ to proper timezone for sonar. This corrected my issue.